# Rotate a webpage clockwise or anticlockwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want to give user the option to rotate the content of my webpage, including images, text and divs. Is this possible?

PS:

I want to rotate the entire webpage. Not just a container div.

Comment: @Tomalak http://jsfiddle.net/KdNNy/1/ CSS3 to the rescue!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use CSS3

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KdNNy/1/

Doesn't work on all browsers though. This example is only for firefox and chrome/safari. Opera should have it as well.  Maybe even IE

**EDIT**

And just in case anyone thinks "oh he's just rotating a DIV!", check this

http://jsbin.com/utupu5/ (full page)

Comment: you are just wrapping the contents in <div id="wrap"> and rotating that particular div. ;) If the page does not contain any DIV is it still possible to be rotated?

Comment: @Selvin I hope you're joking! The second example actually applies the style to the BODY (I had a premonition people would come to the wrong conclusion!). If you're planning on writing your HTML without a body, then I can't help! :P

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery you can use the jRumble plugin to achieve this

The relevant website can be found [here](https://jackrugile.com/jrumble/)

Answer (score 1):

the only way I have heard of to make this achieved is embeding your HTML in a SVG foreign content element.