# How to set CSS on body tag to rotate a page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found the following code while reading a related question at this page: [Rotate a webpage clockwise or anticlockwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498392/rotate-a-webpage-clockwise-or-anticlockwise)

```
html {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

--

My question is how do I set this CSS via JavaScript?

When a visitor clicks on an image, I want to use JavaScript to modify the HTML tag's style using the settings above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675820/use-variables-to-set-in-style-with-javascript

Comment: I accepted the one I did because it's pure Javascript .. however the JQuery ones were great answers too. thanks!

Comment: actually that link had pure javascript codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by putting this in a class, and assigning that class dynamically using JavaScript:

#### CSS:

```
html.rotateme {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute('class', 'rotateme'); //Note that this will override the current class
```

Since you're using a very recent CSS feature, you probably don't need to [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#Browser_compatibility) older browsers.
Therefore, you can also use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) to add a class.

To prevent this from throwing an exception in older browsers, you can check for the existance of it first:

#### JavaScript:

```
document.documentElement.classList && document.documentElement.classList.add('rotateme'); //This won't  override the current class
```

See also: [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/195951/1419007)

Answer (score 0):

You use the [style attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) on the HTML node.

Something like this will do it:

```
var htmlNode = document.documentElement;
htmlNode.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(180deg)';
htmlNode.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(180deg)';
```

Then, to undo the rotate, set the values to an empty string:

```
var htmlNode = document.documentElement;
htmlNode.style.webkitTransform = '';
htmlNode.style.mozTransform = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
$('#wrap').on('click',function(){
$('html').css('-webkit-transform','rotate(180deg)');
$('html').css('-moz-transform','rotate(180deg)');})
```

Comment: Thank you - I like the simplicity of this one.

Comment: I'ts good practice to at least give some explanation in your answer. Also, the OP did not mention the use of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
**JQUERY**

$("#imgID").on("click", function(){
    $('html').css({"-webkit-transform": "rotate(180deg)", "moz-transform": "rotate(180deg)"});
});
```

**only js**

use user2428118's answer, it's a solid solution.

Answer (score 0):

define a class for this:-

```
.htmlrotate {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

onclick of the button, run this:-

```
document.documentElement.classList.add('htmlrotate');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('html').bind('click', function () {
                $('html').css({
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
                    '  -moz-transform': 'rotate(90deg)'
                })
            });
```